# Discord.py - send private message

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord.py

I am using `Replit` to make a discord bot.

```
  if msgtxt in listBadWords:
    await message.channel.send(mention + ", your message has been reported to Arunga")
    await message.channel.send("Please do not repeat the same mistake again. Do not say bad words!")
    user = client.get_user(int(userid))
    await user.send("Arunga, someone said a bad word!")
```

`listBadWords` contains a list of bad words. I want to send a dm to the owner, Arunga, saying '*Someone said a bad word!*' But when I run the code, and test it out, an error comes

```
AttributeError:'NoneType' object has no attribute 'send' for 
await user.send("Arunga, someone said a bad word!")
```

I did put the user is in `userid`, I just didn't want to post the id here.

How do I fix this? Also, this is under `async def on_message():`

Comment: Are you sure `user_id` is correct? The `get_user` function will return `None` if no user with that id is found

Comment: The user needs to also share a server with the bot

Comment: You may also not have the required intents to access the members of some servers

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This is because *User* has no method *send*, *Member* has that, so What I did was get the owner of the server (which stored in member) and then send the message.

Comment: how about some lines of code?